# how to install last version podman (1.7) on last CentOS 8.1

Tags: centos8, podman

I'm tryng to use podman in Centos 8.1. After installing podman with command `sudo dnf install podman`

I have version "1.4.2-stable2". How can I install last version on CentOS? I red this [https://podman.io/getting-started/installation]. According install instruction I realy need building podman from scratch? If so,
is there some more detailed procedure how to do it on Centos?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from:

https://podman.io/getting-started/installation

"*The Kubic project provides updated packages for CentOS 7, 8 and Stream.*"

On the same web page there are instructions of how to enable the Kubic repository.

As of today (24 February 2020) the repository contains podman version 1.8.0.
https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/CentOS_8/x86_64/

(Probably the installation instructions have been rewritten since the question was asked)